# The startup sequence of a program

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a program that auto start when I logon windows 7. I cannot remove it. Is there any method to know the starting process of a program? I want to trace the starting process and remove it. I can found the exe name of the file in registry and also the location of the file.
But I am afraid damaging the windows. So I want to trace it and remove it step by step.

Thanks

Comment: use ProcMon and do a boot logging. In the ProcessTree you can see when the tool was starting: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Answer (score 1):

Run the `msconfig.exe` tool (from either cmd line or from the run dialog box in your start menu).

In there you will be able to selectively disable services/programs etc without damaging the registry.

Comment: Thanks. I have download a program named Autoruns. May I have the boot sequence of the file?

Comment: If you already know the file name, and simply wish to remove it, what purpose does the boot sequence serve you? Provided it is a third party program, and not a core part of Windows itself, simple disabling it from starting (via either msconfig, or autoruns), and then uninstalling (or deleting if no other option) the file(s) should be sufficient.
Unless it is a virus/spyware/malware in which case it is best left to an antivirus program or specific removal tool.

Comment: I mean I can see the files that will autorun during startup of windows . But I want to have the sequence of file loaded during bootup and login. Any tools can let me see that?

Comment: I apologize, i misunderstood the question.

You could enable boot-logging (using the options on the boot tab of msconfig) and that will store the details in c:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt.

However, that will only get you up until the login screen. After that you may be able to sift through the windows event logs and find the answers you need. I am not aware of any third-party apps that will give you all this information.

Answer (score 0):

Download the whole suite tools from Sysinternals.  Process explorer (just one of many very useful tools along with autoruns) allows you to trace every child process and thread coming from any process you (or any other user, including the system) start running.  Very powerful tools though not easy to use without direction; so check out the Windows Internals book or the Sysinternals website for help.